# Fleet bash terminal is not recognising commands

Tags: fleet

I am trying fleet with the bash terminal. I've opened successfully by adding this in the settings.json:

```
{
    "theme": "dark_purple",
    "launchTerminalOnOpen": true,
    "terminal.shellIntegration": true,
    "terminal.profiles": [
        {
            "program": "C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash.exe",
            "args": [""],
            "name": "Bash"
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is that no bash commands is working. I've tried: `ls`, `clear`, `cd <dirName>` and so on. Nothing works. I am getting the message: `bash: clear: command not found`.

Anyone has any ideea?

Answer (score 0):

I look at the documentation for Shell Configuration and see that for linux and MacOS the set `["-l"]` in the args for the Git-Bash Profile, so I added it and it started to work properly:

```json
"terminal.profiles": [
        {
            "program": "C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash.exe",
            "args": ["-l"],
            "name": "Git bash"
        }
    ],
```